# Cannot import module after install

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools

I have installed a python application with the command `python setup.py install` from the project folder, but when I execute it from my bash I get the error:

> ImportError No module named 'skipgram'

This module is imported directly from the `__main__.py` file.
The project source is https://github.com/phanein/deepwalk. You can see that in the *deepwalk* folder there is the file `__main__.py`, and from there, it imports the Skipgram library.
I am a newbie in python programming, maybe this is a problem concerning some path variable?

PS. My actual setup is: Python 3.5 on anaconda3 on Linux Mint 18.

Comment: Can you do `python -c "import deepwalk"` from a folder unrelated to the repo? (say your home folder)? If that works (ie doesnt say no module named 'deepwalk', then maybe try changing the line to  `from deepwalk.skipgram import Skipgram`? If not something is wrong with the install. BTW: I typically like to use `python setup.py develop` so I can change code on the fly.

Comment: Thanks! it works. I excluded the possibility of an error in that code...

Comment: I was thinking about this and the reason is because of absolute imports. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @erotemic, it seems that line 16 in **main**.py should be changed to:

```
from deepwalk.skipgram import Skipgram
```

you can see a discrepancy in the imports when you note that
graph.py and walks.py are in the same folder as skipgram.py, yet graph and walks are imported like this:

```
from deepwalk import graph
from deepwalk import walks as serialized_walks
```